# Any Self-Control like apps on windows that works even after reboot?

Tags: windows

I check out the Self-Control like APPs on Windows, but I am a bit disappointed. What I want is an  Self-Control like apps on windows that have those features:

1.Work even after you reboot the system.

2 Longer time interval (like a week!)

You can do both things with Self-Control, unfortunately, I still haven't find an app has both two features on Windows. Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance.

PS I have tried the freedom, freedom does not work if you reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey i found http://focusme.co/ it says that it can't be undone even after a reboot on the web site. and there're many impressive features on there too. i don't know if it works great or not yet i'm going to try it out right now. it works for chrome, safari, opera, IE and fox. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Coldturkey from https://getcoldturkey.com/ does this. It is quite comprehensive.